# alternative for PlayJsonFormat

Tags: json, scala

I am using PlayJsonFormats in my application to parse scala objects to Json format. But it is very memory intensive and cpu consuming. Is there any alternative for it which is less memory intensive and less cpu consuming.

Comment: I haven't made a comparison, but off the top of my head [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) seems like a good candidate.

Comment: Define - `very memory intensive and cpu consuming`.

Answer (score 1):

For more efficient parsing & serialization of JSON from UTF-8 bytes to Scala case classes & collections I would recommend [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala).

[Here are benchmarks](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/tree/20ba8a60d378ef7e77afb282c551fb4ccf019e8c/benchmark/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/macros) that compare it vs. most popular Scala JSON libraries: circe, jackson-module-scala & play-json.

Alter and run them for your messages on your env. or just see results for Scala 2.12.4 with [JDK 8](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/301c15b1cf194538e1160388be34b6a9a018a5e8/results_jdk8_desktop.txt) & [JDK 9](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/301c15b1cf194538e1160388be34b6a9a018a5e8/results_jdk9_desktop.txt) accordingly.